# Error (mingw32/bin/ld.exe final link failed: No space left on device) building C++ project

Tags: c++, windows, mingw

Basically, yesterday I could program in C++ and today I cannot.

I'm trying to write a simple hello world program in Eclipse Helios using the MinGW C/C++ compiler and I'm running into several problems, and I believe this one to be the root of it.

At first the program compiled and built, but when I tried to run it, an error dialogue said the FirstProject.exe file could not be found/does not exist in the launch configuration. However, I got no errors building and I could clearly see the binaries in Debug/FirstProject.exe in my project explorer. I tried refreshing my project explorer and alas, the file disappeared before my eyes.

I tried building the program again, and that's when I get this error:

c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: final link failed: No space left on device

I don't know what device it's talking about. I have more than 1TB left on this hard drive, so it can't be that. I tried emptying my %Temp% folder and recycling bin (suggestions I found trying to search for a solution for this problem) but to no avail.

It may be worth noting that C++ programs I have written in the past are still running. I'm very new to programming, so I don't know how much information you need, but I'll gladly add anything you need if you think you can help me out.

Comment: Does it provide an error code like `LNK****`?

Comment: you're sure it didn't go and put your project on your Z drive or something?

Comment: The only thing I'm getting from the console is:


c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: final link failed: No space left on device
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
Build error occurred, build is stopped
Time consumed: 179  ms.  

And yes, I've checked the path to the Debug folder several times and it's in the right place.

Comment: I read some things about the temp file being over run as well. The solution I saw recommended increasing your virtual memory. Have you tried that? Being very new to programming it would be hard to imagine simple programs having that issue, if it's even a valid one, though.?.

Comment: How would I go about increasing its virtual memory? And would this fix not be a temporary one?

Comment: Thanks a ton for your help! I increased the allocated space by about 8GB and my problem has disappeared. I appreciate it!

Comment: @CliftonRoberts how did you do that? I also have this problem.

Comment: Who were you @CliftonRoberts? What did you see?!

Answer (score 2):

I just solved this problem on my PC. Actually what the problem in my case was that my windows defender (or any antivirus in someone's case) was blocking **ld.exe** from accessing the protected folder that is the source code folder. You can correct this by going into the Virus and threat protection settings of your PC and then find there for blocked history. You will definitely find there a history record of that blockage. Then just go and allow on this device it. And boom

Comment: I've been battling with this for 8 hours. Finally, I never thought Defender would stop the execution like that.

Answer (score 1):

I just solved this on one of the computers at work which had the same issue when compiling through Codelite. Moving workspaces, rebooting, and reinstalling Codelite didn't fix the problem. I also checked permissions on the /temp folder which were fine.

It turns out there were permission issues/other issues with the disk. Running a disk check fixed a few issues on the disk and that allowed the program to compile. If this doesn't solve your issue you may also want to try disabling any anti-virus/spyware programs and try again.

Answer (score 0):

For me, it was the Windows Defender which was causing the problem I checked the secure Folder controller and I allowed ld.exe and the compiler was once again working fine as it was. I also Cleared the %temp% folder.