# c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: final link failed: No space left on device

Tags: c++, gcc, visual-studio-code, mingw, mingw32

How to fix this error

[image]

Im using mingw and when ever im trying to execute a program this error occurs.

[image]

Comment: Could also be a permissions issue, either in the folder where you are building or in the %TEMP% folder, or even antivirus blocking creation of a file it thinks is a virus. Can you try with antivirus disabled?

Comment: im not using any third party antivirus.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error (mingw32/bin/ld.exe final link failed: No space left on device) building C++ project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12166606/error-mingw32-bin-ld-exe-final-link-failed-no-space-left-on-device-building-c)

Comment: Also, please post the text of code and error messages instead of screenshots. This makes it easier for people to find your question and answer it or learn from it.

Answer (score 0):

Go to settings option [shown as manage] click on settings and then type "save" on the search bar. Scroll down a bit and you will find an unchecked box for the option-"save code before running" under the code runner. Check that box and now run your c file as usual.